# MySQL query to average data if within bounds for graph

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

I have a large amount of data from a data Logging device stored in a MySQL DB that I want to place on a graph, I want to show a months worth of data - the Logging is per second.

I’m using PHP and the Google Charts library to draw the graph as an image client side.

There is no point trying to display 2,628,000 on a graph on a screen so I want to try and get an SQL query to give an average datapoint for say each hour (3600 down to 1), instead of each second, ***unless it is out of bounds***. 
The reason being the whole point in the graph is to show if the value has gone out of bounds and when it did.

The current SQL query to get the data required for last month for example is below, the first problem is PHP is hitting its memory limit before its able to return the data:

> `SELECT Tms, Hz FROM log WHERE Tms >= ".$start." AND Tms <=".$finish." ORDER BY Tms ASC`

The average value *should* be for example 60, the upper limit is 61.5 and the lower limit is 58.5 - any value outside of these should be returned as-is otherwise the hours worth of data should be returned as an average for that hour.

**EDIT:** To answer the comments:

DB structure is:

```
ID - double - AUTO_INCREMENT 
Tms - timestamp 
Hz - float
```

Example Data is:

```
ID     | Tms        | Hz
1      | 1559347082 | 59.91
2      | 1559347083 | 59.98
3      | 1559347084 | 60.53
4      | 1559347085 | 62.03
5      | 1559347086 | 61.11
6      | 1559347087 | 60.93
7      | 1559347088 | 60.88
.......
3606   | 1559350686 | 59.99
```

The expected results would be to have an array of results, all of the values within an hour as an average, unless there is a value out of bounds.

So for the data above, items 1,2,3 would be returned with the average `Tms: 1559347083` and average `Hz: 60.14`, but the next value in the array of results would be `Tms: 1559347085` and `Hz: 62.03`.

Results:

```
Tms: 1559347083 | Hz: 60.14
Tms: 1559347085 | Hz: 62.03
Tms: 1559348886 | Hz: 60.17
```

The maximum amount of points to be averaged or grouped together would be 3600 rows = 1 hour so the graph does show some movement.

One of the current errors when trying to select a large amount of data:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
```

This is happening as the result is being placed into an array so I can add the values for the bounds so there is a clear line on the graph:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $dataPoint = array($row['Tms'], '58.5', $row[$graph], '61.5');
....
    array_push($dataPoints, $dataPoint);
```

This array *($dataPoints)* then gets passed to a function to either output as JSON or output as CSV using [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: This could be a good question, but details are missing. See comment above. It looks like you're measuring the frequency output of a power station, hence the 60 Hz, I get that, but what kind of field is `Tms`? It clearly has to do with time, but is it a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` field? It could also be an `INTEGER`, we don't know. Could you please add these details to your question?

Comment: Sorry edited to add some more details; DB structure and example.
@KIKOSoftware it is indeed monitoring power - an islanded generator to be exact.

Comment: A DOUBLE id? That's new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not logical, or useful, to have one query that does give both, hourly averages, and individual out of bounds values. This requires two queries. So let's start with the first, the hourly average:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(ID) AS CountID,
  DATE(Tms) AS DateTms,
  HOUR(Tms) AS HourTms, 
  AVG(Hz) AS AvgHz
FROM 
  log 
WHERE 
  Tms >= '2019-01-01 12:00:00' AND 
  Tms <= '2019-12-12 12:00:00'
GROUP BY 
  HOUR(Tms)
ORDER BY 
  Tms ASC
```

I've put real dates in the `WHERE` conditions, instead of the undocumented variables `$start` and `$finish`, but these can, of course, be replace. I've added a counter, because it is always useful, and finally, because we report for each hour of the day, I have added a date. The [GROUP BY HOUR(Tms)](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) does the grouping by whole hours.

The second query is about the out of bouds values. It is simply:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  Tms,
  Hz
FROM 
  log 
WHERE 
  Tms >= '2019-01-01 12:00:00' AND 
  Tms <= '2019-12-12 12:00:00' AND
  (Hz < 58.5 OR Hz > 61.5)
ORDER BY 
  Tms ASC
```

You can easily combine the results of these two queries into one array with PHP. However...

I am worried that the last query might produce too much data when there are too much out of bound values. And that's probably what you're saying in your later addition to the question. To solve this you could work with an hourly average of the out of bounds values. You would have to use two queries for this, one for values below the lower limit and one for those above the upper limit. I'll show the first one here:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(ID) AS CountID,
  DATE(Tms) AS DateTms,
  HOUR(Tms) AS HourTms, 
  AVG(Hz) AS AvgHz
FROM 
  log 
WHERE 
  Tms >= '2019-01-01 12:00:00' AND 
  Tms <= '2019-12-12 12:00:00' AND
  Hz < 58.5
GROUP BY 
  HOUR(Tms)
ORDER BY 
  Tms ASC
```

This looks very much like the first query, which is a good thing. The only addition is the range limiting of the `Hz` value. The other query simply has `Hz > 61.5`. The results of the three queries can be collected in an array and displaying in a graph.

The three queries could be forced into one query, but I don't see the advantage of that. With three separate queries you could, for instance, write a PHP function that does the query and gets the results, and all you need to vary, using function parameters, is range limiting and the start/finish times.

Finally a bit about your database. I see you use doubles for the ID, that should probably be an integer. Also don't forget to put indexes on `Tms` and `Hz` otherwise your queries might be very slow.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware for taking the time to post such a detailed response! The only reason I can think of at the moment for one statement would be the order of results, most graphing libraries take the array order as the order to graph the results so it would need extra processing to join the two arrays in order of Tms which I was trying to avoid so PHP doesn’t complain about memory.

Comment: The other thought, mostly out of interest is it possible to do the grouping by number of minutes, so for example instead of grouping by hour, it could be 15minutes, or 30minutes?

Comment: I have also noted the DB design I will make sure any field to be searched is Indexed. The reason behind the double for the ID is, if I store 6 months of 1 second logs that’s potentially 15,768,000 rows / IDs that are needed and thought it run out of int’s?

Comment: PHP arrays are quite easy to order, see [sorting arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Note that you don't need to sort in MySQL if you sort in PHP. Yes, you can group by minutes, 15 minutes would be: `GROUP BY MINUTE(Tms) DIV 15` Note that `MINUTE()` returns 0...59 so you can't use `DIV 13` here, that wouldn't make sense. Finally, the normal [INT type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) can easily hold a number up to 2,147,483,647 which should be more than enough.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware, I didn’t get much chance to try things out today - what I have managed is I can get PHP to fetch all the raw data and output it straight to CSV and copes fine - file size for 1 months data is around 25mb. However if I try to manipulate the array in any way, php claims to run out of memory (now upped to 512mb just to test it), but that was still raw data, once averaged it should drastically reduce the amount of data and should have no problems hopefully.